# AngularJS: How to call function from JQuery when using routing

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I call a function of a controller in Angular from JQuery *when using routing.* **This means there is no controller defined in the HTML!** There are many answers out there for doing this when NOT using routing. For example:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).scope().$apply();
```

But this won't work if you're using routing where the controller is defined in app.js instead of your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the scope defined on the ng-view element

`angular.element($('[ng-view]')).scope()`

and see if it works

Comment: I can get the scope by doing: 

var scope = angular.element($('body')).scope();

This is useful for accessing variables but I can't seem to access a function: scope.myFunction();

Comment: You need the exact scope, parent scope cannot access child scopes.

Comment: Use batarang to see what element has the scope with the functions you are looking for